# Have scientists been able to find an example of a possible White Hole?

Tags: black-holes, white-holes

We went to a planetarium last night last night and watched "Black Holes" narrated by Liam Neeson. If I recall correctly, he said that scientists believe that they have identified a number of Black Holes, and that they think there are White Holes at the bottom of Black Holes and instead of drawing matter/light in, the White Holes spew matter out. I didn't get to ask this question after the session was over: Have scientists been able to find an example of a possible White Hole?

Comment: The Big Bang is pretty much it.

Comment: @Andrew: No, the Big Bang was not a white hole. One way to see this is that an FLRW spacetime is homogeneous, whereas a Schwarzschild spacetime has only rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

No.

It's only a fictional object that agrees with einstein's formulas. But there is no evidence that that objects exists or had existed.

Answer (score 0):

White hole is possible under General Relativity but violates the second law of thermodynamics. It is thus impossible.

Comment: Any reference for that violation?

Comment: @TMS White hole is a black hole, reversed in time.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make the answer on violation obvious for me.

Comment: What may be easier to convince oneself of is that it can't form by gravitational collapse (since nothing can fall in).

Comment: Does it really violate the second law?