# Why do white holes exist?

Tags: black-holes, white-holes

Black holes sort of make sense. Too much mass and too much gravity, so nothing leaves it. But how and why (and where and when) can white holes exist? How can any body not let things enter it while it keeps throwing things out? wouldn't it just simply evaporate? And if black holes also continuously emit radiation, what is the difference between black and white holes? Please correct me if my thinking is going in the wrong direction due to ignorance (or stupidity).

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26401/) is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't exist (assuming appropriate energy conditions). They're just formal solution to Einstein's equations that you get by analytically continuing the metric for an eternal black hole into the infinite past. Even if eternal black holes existed (which we have no reason to believe is the case), you could never observe the existence of the corresponding white hole, since it's in the infinite past.

Comment: +1 but you might explain  to the OP regarding your understanding of  the  infinite  past, I can't find the Wikipedia article I was expecting, there is a lot of philosophical musing though.....

Comment: No.  With negative energy conditions you can fall into a black hole and if you survive go through the wormhole and come out the white hole. It's not limited by the infinite past, but by the existence or not of exotic matter. It's not ruled in, but with unknowns yet on what happens in quantum gravity you can't say no for sure either. It is somewhat speculative, but no more than many other quantum gravity speculations. At least you could answer the scientific question, of how does GR cause a white hole, even if theoretically and un-found.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb, but can you please explain why we get the solutions to be a white hole (why not an alternate universe...), and why does a black hole have to be eternal? (it could be formed by a star collapse a couple of million years ago)

Comment: @BobBee Yes, that's why I said "assuming appropriate energy conditions." If you don't impose any energy conditions, then (loosely speaking) practically anything can happen in GR.

Comment: @Mustafa The white hole solution only appears if we [analytically continue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) the Schwarzchild metric beyond the original coordinate ranges, and no one really knows if this procedure produces anything physically significant, or if they're just extraneous mathematical solutions. So anything we say about white holes is largely speculative.

Comment: @Mustafa  For realistic black holes formed by collapsing matter (like a star), you *don't* get a white hole in the infinite past - just regular Minkowski-like spacetime. Another reason to doubt the physical significance of white holes.

Comment: @TParker. 'Practically anything can happen in GR' is nonsense. You're generalizing from little knowledge. The only need for exotic matter is not for the solution but for stabitlity and quantum gravity will have a role there. Your definition of 'largely speculative' would have ruled out any new physics over history. Analytical continuation just means another coordinate system in this case, and coordinate systems are a dime a dozen according to the principle of covariance. I'm not saying white holes are real, but am saying you don't know, you are doing negative speculation.

Comment: @BobBee Please refrain from ad hominem attacks. By "practically anything can happen in GR" I simply mean that without imposing any physically-motivated constraints on the stress-energy tensor, any (second-differentiable) metric at all is a formal solution to Einstein's equations.

Comment: @BobBee And I have no idea why you interpreted my comment that white holes are "largely speculative" as any kind of indictment or claim that we shouldn't think about them, nor do I understand how a definition can "rule out new physics." I didn't claim that white holes definitely do not exist, I was simply pointed out that the OP's presupposition that "white holes exist" is invalid, as they may or may not exist.

Comment: @TParker I think your comments spoke for themselves. I have no problem with your measured last comment. And I do agree that it doesn't seem likely. I just believe that speculative questions, when the OP is trying to understand and not sell unphysical arguments, are best answered without too many adjectives (though some are needed, we're not fact machines, and can explain the assessment) and more descriptions of what people have found. I still remember the negative energy solutions of relativistic quantum mechanics, which were eventually correctly interpreted as anti-particles.